# Escaping curly brackets in source XML in XQuery

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xquery, basex

Using XQuery (BaseX implementation), I need to process a set of XML records that may contain pairs of curly brackets within element text (e.g., `<a>Abc {de} fg</a>`). Right now, I am preprocessing the records outside of XQuery to ensure that these characters have been escaped as double brackets (`<a>Abc {{de}} fg</a>`).

Is there a standard way to escape these characters *within* XQuery in order to prevent them from being executed as an expression?

Comment: If you have an XML source, don't you parse that with `doc` or `collection` where it then shouldn't matter that there are curly braces? After all, they only have a special meaning in XQuery code, but not in XML input.

Comment: You're right, of course. My confusion came from trying to work with XQuery from a Python client library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to embed arbitrary UTF-8 encoded XML input in your query, you can use the XQuery 3.1 string constructor and `fn:parse-xml`:

```
let $string := ``[<a>Abc {de} fg</a>]``
return fn:parse-xml($string)
```

The only thing you should ensure is that your XML string does not contain the characters ``` ]`` ```.

In general, the safest way is to save your input in external files (or in a database) and address it via `fn:doc`, `fn:collection`, `fetch:xml`, `db:open`, etc.